# a question when reading the classical book Design Patterns:Element of Reusable Object-Oriented Software

Tags: design-patterns

I'm learning the design pattern by reading the classical book of GOF -- Design Patterns:Element of Reusable Object-Oriented Software.In [Chap2](https://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Estotts/GOF/hires/chap2.htm):a case study, we define a Glyph abstract class for all objects that can appear in a document structure.In Glyph,there is a method and its description

> `virtual void Bounds(Rect&)`: The Bounds operation returns the rectangular area that the glyph occupies. It returns the opposite corners of the smallest rectangle that contains the glyph. Glyph subclasses redefine this operation to return the rectangular area in which they draw.

Why the return type of Bounds operation is **void** according to its description?

Comment: `Rect&` is known as an [output parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Output_parameters).

Comment: it seems that the Bouds operation should only have the private access:it will only be used within the class.that's right?

Answer (score 0):

*"It returns"* here refers to fact that `Bounds()` updates `Rect` which is [argument passed by reference](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/) or "output argument" rather than initializing a new instance of `Rect` and returning it as return value.

Note that GOF is not the newest book and while concepts (design patterns) presented there are still valid, language use and idioms changed since the examples were written.

Comment: it seems that the Bouds operation should only have the private access:it will only be used within the class.that's right?